# Convert Doctrine 1 schema to Doctrine 2 entities?

Tags: doctrine, doctrine-orm

A few months ago there was a command to convert a doctrine 1 schema file to doctrine 2 entities, however, this command no longer exists.

I've just start using the Symfony2 RC1.

Is there a reason it was removed? I have a doctrine 1 schema file which is 600 lines of YML... having a conversion tool would be incredibly useful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it is difficult to do such a conversion. This is because you don't have the behaviours of Doctrine 1 in Version 2 (Timestampable, Versionable...)

But you can always create your Entities with the doctrine:mapping:import commandline task from your existing database.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that you need to manually copy the doctrine bin files since they don't come with Symfony2 by default.

See http://www.doctrine-project.org/docs/orm/2.1/en/reference/tools.html